# Prioritize different network connections

Tags: networking

I'm planning to use my Pi as a wireless NAS and use with XBMC on my childrens Android pads.
The Pi is configured with two wireless adapters, one (wlan1) that is configured with static IP-address and configured as accesspoint. The other should try to connect to specific accesspoints or find open networks. How could i configure this setup and make it reconfigure automatically if "better" connections are avaliable:

`1 st choice: eth0
2 nd choice: wlan0 SSID "home" password "Secret123"
alt. 2 nd choice: wlan0 SSID "work" password "MoreSecret123456"
3 rd choice: wlan0 SSIS "3GAccessPoint" password "MyCell123"
4 th choice: wlan0 any open wireless network`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wicd-curses`

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-curses
```

[image]

You leave your access point wireless set up as is and inside wicd cursos you select the wireless that is going to connect to other access point.

[image]

Its got a heavy python dependency but is very reliable and easy to setup via SSH.

You can connect to the networks you need and it will always stay connected to the best one in range. With some more advanced config file editting I am sure you can add custom rules.

Another way is to try WPA-SUPPLICANT but I always found that very unstable, and I tried various WiFi and power and all sorts.